# If-statement not functioning properly in NetBeans

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I got this code down below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Integer intNumber = (Integer)jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
    String text = null;

    if (intNumber <= 3) {
        text = "Less than or equal to three";
    } else if (intNumber > 3) {
        text = "Bigger than three";
    }
    jLabel1.setText(text);
}
```

But if I run this code in Netbeans and choose 4 (which is bigger than 3) in the Combobox, the jLabel1 prints out "Less than or equal to three", even though it obviously is bigger. Could someone explain why?

Comment: The indexing starts at `0`, maybe that is the cause. If you select the first item `getSelectedIndex()` will return `0`

Comment: I think Titus is probably right.  I'd wager that your combo box lists 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc.  Where the index returned from jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() will give you 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

Comment: @Titus @ Pherion Thank you guys so much for your help! This solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You used `getSelectedIndex()` instead of `getSelectedItem()`.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Integer intNumber = (Integer)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    String text = null;

    if (intNumber <= 3) {
        text = "Less than or equal to three";
    } else if (intNumber > 3) {
        text = "Bigger than three";
    }
    jLabel1.setText(text);
}
```